# How to add and remove screens to RAM manually through code in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, screen, rerender

## Problem

I am new to React Native. Recently I faced with such a problem: when I move from the **login screen** to the **signup screen**, the **signup screen** is loaded again each time. How I can load the screen only once and store it in RAM or do something like that, to avoid rerendering? How to add and remove screens to RAM manually through code.

## Environment

- MacOS 13.0.1 (M1)
- React Native CLI
- dependencies:
  @react-navigation/native: ^6.1.2,
  @react-navigation/stack: ^6.3.11,
  expo-linear-gradient: ^12.0.1,
  react: 18.1.0,
  react-native: ^0.70.6,
  react-native-color-picker: ^0.6.0,
  react-native-event-listeners: ^1.0.7,
  react-native-gesture-handler: ^2.9.0,
  react-native-localization: ^2.3.1,
  react-native-paper: ^5.1.3,
  react-native-paper-dropdown: ^1.0.7,
  react-native-safe-area-context: ^4.4.1,
  react-native-screens: ^3.19.0,
  react-native-vector-icons: ^9.2.0,

## Code

**App.navigator.tsx**

```
import React from "react"
import { createStackNavigator, StackView } from "@react-navigation/stack"
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { SignupScreen } from "./screens/signup/signup.screen"
import { LoginScreen } from "./screens/login/login.screen"
import { HomeScreen } from "./screens/home/home.screen"
import { SettingsScreen } from "./screens/settings/settings.screen"

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

// App navigation. Used to relocate between the app's screens
const AppNavigator = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false,
                                         headerMode: "screen",
                                         cardStyle: {backgroundColor: "white"}}}
                         initialRouteName="Login">
            <Stack.Screen name="Login"
                          component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="SignUp"
                          component={SignupScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Home"
                          component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Settings"
                          component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>



    </NavigationContainer>
)

export default AppNavigator
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Provider as PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';
import { EventRegister } from 'react-native-event-listeners';
import AppNavigator from './app.navigator';
import mainAppTheme, {fontTheme} from './config/theme';
import themeContext from './config/themeContext';
import { CHANGE_THEME_LITERAL } from './config/theme';

const App = () => {
    // Theme update
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(mainAppTheme)
    useEffect(() => {
        let eventListener = EventRegister.addEventListener(CHANGE_THEME_LITERAL, (theme) => {
            setTheme(theme)
        })
        return () => {
            EventRegister.removeEventListener(eventListener.toString())
        }
    })

  return (
    <themeContext.Provider value={theme}>
    <PaperProvider theme={fontTheme}>
        <AppNavigator />
    </PaperProvider>
    </themeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Login.screen.tsx**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, View } from "react-native";
import { Button, Card, TextInput } from "react-native-paper";
import { PasswordComponent } from "../../components/password.component";
import mainAppTheme, {appTheme} from "../../config/theme";
import themeContext from "../../config/themeContext";
import { loginScreenTrans } from "../../translations/login.screen.trans"
import { loginStyle } from "./login.style";

interface LoignScreenProps{
    navigation: any
}

// Login app screen. Meets new users
export const LoginScreen = (props:LoignScreenProps) => {

    // Theme update
    const theme: appTheme = useContext(themeContext)
    loginScreenTrans.setLanguage(theme.lang)

    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={loginStyle().content}>
            <View style={loginStyle().view}>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Title title="BuildIn" titleStyle={loginStyle().cardTitle}></Card.Title>
                    <Card.Content>
                        <TextInput selectionColor={theme.colors.mainAppColor}
                                   activeUnderlineColor={theme.colors.mainAppColor}
                                   label={loginScreenTrans.email}
                                   keyboardType="email-address"
                                   style={loginStyle().email} />

                        <PasswordComponent label={loginScreenTrans.password}
                                           color={theme.colors.mainAppColor.toString()}
                                           style={loginStyle().password}/>

                        <Button uppercase={false}
                                textColor={theme.colors.mainAppTextColor}>
                                {loginScreenTrans.forgot}
                            </Button>

                            <Button buttonColor={theme.colors.mainAppColor}
                                textColor={"#ffffff"}
                                uppercase={true}
                                mode="contained"
                                onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate("Home");
                                                props.navigation.reset({
                                                    index: 0,
                                                    routes: [{ name: 'Home' }]})
                                                    }}>
                                {loginScreenTrans.login}
                            </Button>

                        <Button uppercase={true}
                                textColor={mainAppTheme.colors.mainAppTextColor}
                                onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("SignUp")}>
                                {loginScreenTrans.signup}
                            </Button>

                    </Card.Content>
                </Card>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

## What i tried

Next steps changed nothing in my case:

1. Use `enableFreeze(true)` and `enableScreens(true)` at the top of loaded screen file and top of navigation file.
2. Wrap my screen in `React.memo()`
3. Set `freezeOnBlur: true` prop into `<Stack.Navigator>`
4. `navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.reset({ routes[...]`

Maybe I used it incorrectly, I would be grateful if someone could explain to me why.

But it seems that the problem is specifically in the way react navigation works. And I don't know how to set it up the way I want.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why are you trying to prevent rendering?

Comment: I want to know how to add and remove screens to RAM manually through code. For example: when you exit the screen, the filled fields are also erased. Yes, fields can be saved using storage, but the screen still loads again.

Comment: That's not possible. You need a state that survives from a navigation lifecycle.

Comment: I think you are making such a verdict too soon. The question is how to manually leave screens in the navigation life cycle, not how to save them after the cycle is over. Parent screens remain unchanged in memory after switching to child screens. Therefore, there must be a way to manipulate the desired screens manually. It seems to me that the way should be linked to a method like navigation.reset(), or navigation.dispatch()